# Keras: why the accuracy not changing when training

Tags: keras

I try to run the [churn_modeling.csv](https://github.com/2blam/ML/blob/master/deep_learning/Churn_Modelling.csv) file in Keras but I don't the model learning. Here is my code:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

#read from CSV file ,convert categorial value to one-hot-encoding and convert the result to numpy array
df=pd.read_csv("churn_modelling.csv")
X=pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Geography','Gender'])
X=X[['CreditScore','Age','Tenure','Balance','NumOfProducts','HasCrCard','IsActiveMember','EstimatedSalary','Geography_France','Geography_Germany','Geography_Spain','Gender_Female','Gender_Male','Exited']]
dataset=X.as_matrix()


X_train=dataset[:,0:13]
Y_train=dataset[:,13]

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(26, input_dim=13,  activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.02)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train,Y_train, validation_split=0.05, epochs=10, batch_size=200)
```

This is the output I got:
Train on 9500 samples, validate on 500 samples

```python
Epoch 1/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.7996 - acc: 0.7637 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 2/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 3/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 4/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 5/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 6/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 7/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 8/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 9/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
Epoch 10/10
9500/9500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.3085 - acc: 0.7947 - val_loss: 2.8045 - val_acc: 0.8260
```

Even if I run the program with 100 epochs, I still get the same result val_acc: 0.8260. Thank you

Comment: What happens if you reduce your batch size? Maybe down to like 24.

Comment: Thank you. I change the batch size to 24 and delete one gender column and softmax activation function like this model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax')). But the accuracy and the loss in the output didn't change.

Comment: Could you try to use ```categorical_crossentropy``` instead of ```binary_crossentropy``` (because you already use a one-hot-vector)

Comment: If you want to do binary classification, you can just keep the output `y` as categorical (0 or 1), and sigmoid with `binary_crossentropy` will work fine.

Comment: So, just to understand: you have a small dataset (10,000 records), modeled with a small neural network, you reach a validation accuracy of ~ 83% in binary classification... and you complain that the model "is not learning"???

Comment: @desertnaut I ma looking for an explanation I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if training set is rescaled, the accuracy improves slightly 86%. I have used the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
rescaledX_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```